# Test the rendering of HTML and CSS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I need to test if the following HTML code and the CSS of that page results into a `red` and `line-through` price like:

[image]

```
<div class="listOldPrice">
  <span>
    <span class="wasPriceEuroDestination">&euro;&nbsp;</span>
    719.
    <b>-</b>
  </span>
</div>
```

Can I do that with Selenium? How?

Comment: You can check the classes which are applied to element. AFAIK you cant check the visuals

Comment: Would using the `getCssValue()` method help in this case perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Ruby solution:

```
price = @driver.find_element(:class, 'wasPriceEuroDestination')
assert_equal(true, price.displayed?)
assert_equal("rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)", price.css_value('color'))
assert_equal("line-through", price.css_value('text-decoration'))
```

Answer (score 0):

That is usually handled by a class.  Since classes aren't the prettiest to match on since they aren't very unique, it's difficult to give you a complete selector, but i'll put some placeholders in:

In Java, you could do something like:

```
assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#someParentOfThatPrice div.listOldPrice")).isDisplayed());
```

If this test fails, that means that it can't find the element, ergo, it's **not** crossed out.

Comment: I need a test which tests the visual display (red and line-through). It is a test to check if the CSS works correct.